# Inputting complicated equation into Wolfram

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am having a bear of a time getting this equation into Wolfram so I can solve it for E(r) = 1000.

[image: Equation]

[image: Equation2]

Everything is constant except for little r, which is the cursive r in each term. In case anyone is wondering, this is the expression for the electric field from the center of a hydrogen atom. r is for radius.

Can anyone put this in and link me to the solution? Much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot read all of it. Is that an $M$ or $\pi$?

Comment: @Amzoti I think (after staring for a bit) all of the things that look like m/$\pi$ are actually $r$, and that is what OP wants to find. After more staring, I would not swear by it.

Comment: @J.W.Perry: Thanks, for a sec I thought, man I am getting old! :-)

Comment: The m-like things are actually lowercase r's. The only pi is between the 4 and epsilon naught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, but you can put in your constants and then play around with defining them using the proper names.

```
  solve (.2)/(4 pi .5 r^2)(1 - e^(-2 r /.6)(2(r/.6)^2+2(r/.6)+1)) = 1000 for r
```

See this [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28.2%29%2F%284+pi+.5+r%5E2%29%281+-+e%5E%28-2+r+%2F.6%29%282%28r%2F.6%29%5E2%2B2%28r%2F.6%29%2B1%29%29+%3D+1000+for+r) page.

By defining parameters, I mean, something like:

```
 q = .2, solve (q)/(4 pi .5 r^2)(1 - e^(-2 r /.6)(2(r/.6)^2+2(r/.6)+1)) = 1000 for r
```

[*Here*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=q%3D.2%2C+t+%3D+.4%2C+a%3D.6%2C+solve+%28q%29%2F%284+pi+t+r%5E2%29%281+-+e%5E%28-2+r+%2Fa%29%282%28r%2Fa%29%5E2%2B2%28r%2Fa%29%2B1%29%29+%3D+1000+) you can define your parameters:

```
q=.2, t = .4, a=.6, solve (q)/(4 pi t r^2)(1 - e^(-2 r /a)(2(r/a)^2+2(r/a)+1)) = 1000
```

For the parameters you posted, I got two solutions:

- $\large r = 7.71723 \times 10^{-20}$
- $\large r = 1.19945 \times 10^{-6}$

Note, there are other options:

- Get a free [*CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) like SAGE, Maxima or others. These also have working online copies.
- Use Mathics.org

Comment: Can you solve this for me with q = 1.6*10^-19, epsilon nought = 8.85*10^-12, a = 0.529 * 10^-10. I'm having trouble defining the constants and still getting it to solve.

Comment: I got an answer, which was r = 4.76 * 10^-15 m

Comment: It is possible I am doing something wrong with the solver, but currently do not see what that is. What did you use?

Comment: My TI 83. I think I can explain what's going wrong with your solver. The function is actually increasing for extremely small values of r, then decreasing for all other ones. Based on some other calculations I did, it should be around the order of 10^-17.

Comment: Could you rewrite for me your equation in ASCII form ? I am almost blind and I cannot read the front term.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by ASCII

Comment: In words, I have $q$ divided by the product $4 \times \pi \times t \times r^2$. Is that the term you were speaking of?

Comment: At the front end of the equation, I defined each parameter and its value (I used small values and it works. When I change to the value you wanted, it goes south on me and I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Okay, got my solver working. For the parameters you provided, it found two solutions. $r = 7.71723*10^{-20}$ or $r = 1.19945*10^{-6}$ Still not sure how to get Wolfram Alpha to do it. Regards

Comment: @user99984: I added the results for the values you asked.

Comment: Excellent, the first value is close to what I would expect. How did you get these?

Comment: Ooh! sliders too! +1

Comment: I see you're up at 5:00 am to catch you morning fix! ;-)

Comment: Yes, yesterday was fun - seeing all the little "goblins", and a few not so little goblins!